# RSpec mock_model and inherited_resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, inherited-resources

I'm trying to write spec for inherited_resources controller. I decided to mock all integration with the database using rspec's mock_model. Unfortunately I can't write spec for create and update action because I'm getting the following error: https://gist.github.com/936947
Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue using flexmock.

the cause is that it does not use the `update_attributes` method to make the routing decision. It checks the `resource.errors` to see whether it is empty.

So to get it to respond properly, we will need to mock out the `errors` method as well.

Here is the pertinent code @line 248 in lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb

```
  def respond_with_dual_blocks(object, options, &block) #:nodoc:
    args = (with_chain(object) << options)

    case block.try(:arity)
      when 2
        respond_with(*args) do |responder|
          blank_slate = InheritedResources::BlankSlate.new
          if object.errors.empty?
            block.call(responder, blank_slate)
          else
            block.call(blank_slate, responder)
          end
        end
      when 1
        respond_with(*args, &block)
      else
        options[:location] = block.call if block
        respond_with(*args)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Mock out the errors method with what, exactly? I've come across this exact same issue...

Comment: Ah right, I've used stub_chain with `team.stub_chain(:errors, :empty?).and_return(false)` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The failure messages are about the inability to access named routes from inside the controller, so I'm not sure that this has anything to do with mock_model. Have  you tried the same examples using real models?